# AWS Cognito with non-AWS Resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

My question is about AWS Cognito Security Services- can AWS Cognito be used for any resources outside AWS Cloud e.g an API developed published on Apigeea API Gateway?

I searched through AWS Documents and on Google

I want to create SSO with AWS Cognito like SAML-based SSO federation where Resources/ Services can be anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can. Kindly see the App Clinet option in Cognito. 
However, Apigee also needs to have the capability to integrate.